# Is there any way to disable predictive bar of keyboard in ios 8?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios8, uiresponder

So we have predictive bar in iOS 8 but it covers my input field above the keyboard. I found only one solution to hide it by setting correction of textView to NO. But it turns off correction as well which is not good.Any suggestions?Is there any api for this stuff from Apple?

Answer (score 10):

Setting `autocorrectionType` to `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo` on the UITextView in question (or correction to NO in IB) disables autocorrect as well as the predictive text bar in iOS 8. There doesn't appear to be a way to disable just the predictive bar however.

Comment: make sure to set the keyboard type to asciiCapable. [Check this post, it is SwiftUI but it also applies to UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74034938/2303865)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from the UI too. When selecting the text field element, change the **Correction** option to **No**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    UITextInputAssistantItem* item = [textField inputAssistantItem];
    item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
    item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

In later iOS versions only this worked for me:

```swift
searchBar.textContentType = UITextContentType(rawValue: "")
```