# TextField with autocorrectionDisabled() still shows predictive text bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, keyboard, textfield

I experimenting with the SwiftUI TextField and want to get rid of the predictive suggestion bar above the keyboard:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

            TextField("Hello", text: $text)
                .autocorrectionDisabled()
                .textContentType(.init(rawValue: ""))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

When typing, the predictive suggestions are still shown above the keyboard.  Is there a way to get rid of these as well?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is written [there](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/autocorrectiondisabled(_:)). You should use `autocorrectionDisabled` instead.

Comment: @LeoDabus Just found that too, but doesn't help.

Comment: AFAIR there is some textContentType you need to set at least for UIKit. There might be something related to SwiftUI as well. Try this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid/textcontenttype(_:)-1pzp

Comment: try adding `.textContentType("")`

Comment: @LeoDabus `""` didn't work as it was expecting an optional enum value.  Both `.none` and `nil` don't make any difference.

Comment: I remember that this would solve predictive issues with UIKit,

Comment: try `.textContentType(.init(rawValue: ""))`

Comment: @LeoDabus Even when I set it to `.countryName` or similar and type `F` I get `For` and `Find` as suggestions.

Comment: @LeoDabus Still the same.

Comment: Thats weird. I remember that this would solve the issue with UIKit. Not sure what else you need to set.

Comment: @LeoDabus Just tried a plain `TextField()` and it has the same issue/behaviour. (Edited/Simplified the code.)

Comment: I would insist with `.textContentType(.init(rawValue: ""))` instead of `.none`. Believe me it is not the same.

Comment: @LeoDabus Still the same, also without `.autocorrectionDisabled()`.  Also have no modifiers (at all actually) above my view that could affect this.

Comment: It works for me with the simulator

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm running on iOS 16.0 simulator with deployment to iOS 15.0. You?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cch04tcwa83zidp/screen%20shot%20keyboard.jpg?dl=1

Comment: iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm also on iPhone 14 Pro.  This is maddening.  It's getting late here, I'll try a fresh app with clean view tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome target 15 works as well

Comment: @LeoDabus Tried a new project and it doesn't help.  See edits.

Comment: You need to add `.keyboardType(.asciiCapable)` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `autocorrectionDisabled` instead of `disableAutocorrection`, add `.textContentType(.init(rawValue: ""))` and don't forget to set the keyboard to `.keyboardType(.asciiCapable)`. Default keyboard doesn't work. I don't know why.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            TextField("Hello", text: $text)
                .keyboardType(.asciiCapable)
                .autocorrectionDisabled(true)
                .textContentType(.init(rawValue: ""))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `.asciiCapable` did the trick. Thanks a lot!